# Procurando keywords no ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Estou registrando alguns objetos do tipo:

```
[{
  nome: "bom_atendimento",
  chaves: ["bem atendido", "atendimento bom"]
},
{
  nome: "ruim_atendimento",
  chaves: ["pessimo atendimento", "atendimento ruim"]
}]
```

Preciso que essas chaves sejam identificadas em um texto.

Exemplos de texto de entrada / resultado que eu preciso:

1 - "Esse atendimento foi ruim"

resultado:

```
    {
       nome: "ruim_atendimento",
      chaves: ["pessimo atendimento", "atendimento ruim"]
    }
```

2 - "Hoje eu fui bem atendido"

resultado:

```
{
      nome: "bom_atendimento",
      chaves: ["bem atendido", "atendimento bom"]
    }
```

Como estou indexando:

```
{
      "settings": {
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "custom_keyword_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard",
              "filter": [
                "asciifolding",
                "lowercase",
                "custom_stopwords",
                "custom_stemmer"
              ]
            },
            "custom_shingle_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace",
              "filter": [
                "custom_stopwords",
                "custom_stemmer",
                "asciifolding",
                "lowercase",
                "custom_shingle"
              ]
            }
          },
          "filter": {
            "custom_stemmer": {
              "type": "stemmer",
              "name": "brazilian"
            },
            "custom_stopwords": {
              "type": "stop",
              "stopwords": [
                "a",
                "as",
                "o",
                "os",
                "fui"
              ],
              "ignore_case": true
            },
            "custom_shingle": {
              "type": "shingle",
              "min_shingle_size": 2,
              "output_unigrams": false,
              "output_unigrams_if_no_shingles": true
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "mappings": {
        "meutipo": {
          "properties": {
            "nome": { "type": "keyword" },
            "chaves": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "custom_keyword_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer": "custom_shingle_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Minha pesquisa: 
     {
           index: 'meuindex',
           type: 'meutipo',

```
      body:{
         "query": {
            "match": { "chaves": "texto"} }
          }
      }
 }
```

Não estou obtendo resultados. Quando removo `custom_shingle` do filtro `custom_shingle_analyzer`, qualquer texto que possua "atendimento" retorna os dois registros do ES.

Preciso que só tenha resultados, se o texto conter pelo menos uma expressão exatamente igual a uma `chave` registrada no ES. No meu exemplo:

Para obter o resultado:

```
 {
      nome: "bom_atendimento",
      chaves: ["bem atendido", "atendimento bom"]
    }
```

o texto deve conter "bem atendido" ou "atendimento bom".

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? Usando sinônimos e shingle?

Elasticsearch version: 5.1.2

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Consegue descrever um pouco melhor como está indexado no ES, pelo menos 3 exemplos de como seria a consulta(input) e como deveria ser a resposta(output)?

Comment: @TomMelo editei minha pergunta. Ficou mais claro?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode obter o resultado utilizando **Function Score Query**.

Documentação: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html

Supondo que você esteja utilizando o [elasticsearch-js](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) como client do Elasticsearch:

**1 - A primeira parte é a utilização da [query por termos](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html), já que a "frase exata" pode nunca dar "match" na sua query:**

```
var terms = "Hoje eu fui bem atendido".split(" ");

es.search({
  index: 'seu-index',
  type: 'seu tipo',
  body: {
    query: {
      terms: { chaves: terms }
    }
  }
}, function(error, result) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
});
```

Mesmo utilizando a query por termos o ES vai retornar todas as chaves pois as duas contém termos em comum("atendimento" e etc).

**2 - Adicionando a Function Score para filtrar as chaves:**

Note no score da primeira query, a chave "bom_atentimento" obteve um score maior que a "ruim_atentimento", portanto podemos definir um score mínimo.

```
var terms = "Hoje eu fui bem atendido".split(" ");

es.search({
  index: 'seu-index',
  type: 'seu tipo',
  body: {
    query: {
      function_score: {
        query: { terms: { chaves: terms } },
        min_score: 0.7
      }
    }
  }
}, function(error, result) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
});
```

Dessa forma somente a chave que atinge o score mínimo é retornada.

**Dica**: Pra que você precisa guardar o termo "atendimento" na chave?

Guardando apenas termos relevantes para buscar na frase deixaria sua busca muito mais simples, ex:

```
 {
   nome: "ruim_atendimento",
   chaves: ["pessimo", "ruim", "horrivel"]
 }
```

Comment: Entendo a dica. Mas, em alguns casos eu ainda preciso de tokens com 2 ou mais palavras

Comment: Entendi, vou tentar fazer o match do texto exato dentro de sua lista da chaves. O cenário que descrevi utilizando terms e function_score não te atende então, certo?

Comment: Em alguns casos não me atende. Outro exemplo :  
`{
   nome: "produto_x",
   chaves: ["nomeproduto x"]
 },
{
   nome: "produto_x_2",
   chaves: ["nomeproduto x 2"]
 },
{
   nome: "produto y",
   chaves: ["nomeproduto y"]
 }` 
Com a pesquisa: "Ver mais sobre nomeproduto x". É aceitável no meu caso que apareçam nos resultados "produto_x" e "produto_x_2".  Apenas com pontuação, "produto y" também aparece, pois são bem parecidos. Por isso preciso que sejam encontrados em um *texto* expressões exatamente iguais a `chaves` registradas (pelo menos essa é a maneira que eu consigo pensar)